# FAT32 root cluster. Дополнительные файлы

Tags: cluster, fat32

Изначально у меня на диске лежало несколько файлов. При просмотре в hex-редакторе они присутствуют. После этого я создал папку в root и переместил файлы в неё. При просмотре в hex-редакторе я в root cluster вижу мои перемещённые файлы, они же присутствуют в папке. 
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а точно переместили?) не копировали, не сим-линк делали и права на запись были?)

Comment: Средствами ФС файлов на старом месте больше не видно, она сработала корректно. Перезапись информации, оставшейся на месте старых файлов никто не гарантировал, а вы ее ждете.

Comment: @pavel Да точно переместил. Все права присутствовали

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов получается что даже после удаления файлов они будут присутствовать в heх-таблице?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я понял что эти файлы отмечаются байтом(0xE5) и впоследствии будут перезаписаны. Благодарю за объяснение. А что будет происходить если весь кластер root будет забит информацией, где он будет хранить ссылку на следующий кластер?

Comment: @ВалентинЧикунов Я не помню деталей реализации FAT. Вполне возможно что когда кончатся пустые элементы дойдет очередь до помеченных удаленными.